# Environment variables

Tags: python, logging, mechanize, twill

I use the module `mechanize` in order to log in a site. When I `import twill.commands` without any other apparent use, some debug messages [0] are displayed [1]. When I delete it, these messages disappear.

How can I see what is changed in the environment in order to emulate it and remove this dependency?

[0] Using the logging module.
[1] More specifically, I am interested in a `Following HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH` message.

UPDATE: It turned out that there is a bug in twill.commands which was creating an error when trying to follow the `HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH` header. After removing the `import twill.commands` and the ugly work around it, everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess - without digging in the libraries - is that twill is instantiating a logger, and mechanize is doing the [Right Thing](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) for a library, logging if logging has been turned on, not if not.

To enable the logging of `mechanize` configure a [logging.basicConfig](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#simple-examples) root in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

`twill` uses `mechanize` internally, you can log into a web site directly with `twill`.

To follow `http-equiv` redirection, just use the [`go` command](http://twill.idyll.org/commands.html).

> `go <url>` -- visit the given URL. The Python function returns the final URL visited, **after all redirects**.

To debug `http-equiv` redirects, enable the relevant debug level.

> `debug <what> <level>` -- turn on or off debugging/tracing for
>       various functions. The first argument is either 'http' to show HTTP headers, 'equiv-refresh' to test HTTP EQUIV-REFRESH headers, or 'commands' to show twill commands. The second argument is '0' for off, '1' for on.

Comment: When the `twill` is imported, I can't follow the `http-equiv` redirection using the `go` command. It always raises an exception about urllib...

Comment: Works here. Try installing latest twill from http://code.google.com/p/twill/source/checkout

Comment: I have to use the version in Debian archives, which admittedly is rather old.